# ZF2 ZfcUser cannot resolve "_form.phtml"

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I cannot get ZfcUser to work with my application which is based on ZF2 skeleton. For all the routes (register, login, ...) I get the following error:

> Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "_form.phtml"; resolver could not resolve to a file

The form.phtml is of course in the right place. However, it seems that the resolver is looking for the file only in "/view" while it should be looking in "/view/zfc-user/user/_form.phtml".

The ZfcUser module's template_path_stack contains "**DIR** . '/../view'", however, I do not understand how ZF2 constructs the sub-dirs and which configuration might impair this logic.

Thanks for any hints

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding this in your modules `template_path_stack`? Otherwise this should solve your problem:

```
'zfc-user' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
```

You can read about it in the [ZfcUser wiki on GitHub](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/wiki/How-to-override-built-in-view-scripts)